# String length as you are typing in javascript

Tags: javascript, passwords

I set the character validation for a password input to be 8. I want to input a function or an instruction (as the case may be) in javascript so that as I am typing the password, the background will be red if it isn't up to 8 characters yet and it would change to green if it has reached 8 characters and above

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far and where you are stuck.

Comment: Please read this and edit your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
function checkLength(textField) {
 var strText = textField.value;
 // if without spaces
 strText = strText.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");

 if(strText.length > 8) {
  textField.style.backgroundColor = "#ff0000";
 } else {
  textField.style.backgroundColor = "#00FF00";
 }
}
```

```html
<input type="password" name="sometextfield" onkeyup="checkLength(this);" />
```